# Instantiating TestContext programttically

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to run some specific tests from a different project than the unit tests itself, but the tests use TestContext and according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404699(v=vs.80).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx 
this is instantiated from within the framework.

Is it possible to call unit tests methods from a different project?

Comment: What do you mean with run? From within VS or directly using mstest.exe? And is different project == different assembly? Do you want to use the existing TestContext or include another?

Comment: if you have UTs in the different project you have taken a reference to the testframework dlls. So testcontext is already available. Not sure what issue are you facing.

Comment: @allen : it doesnt initialise! the variable

Comment: Doubt that is correct. Because this would be a major bug. File a issue via connect or contact Microsoft support